# Exception in do while loop

Tags: java, loops, exception

I have this piece of code:

```
do {
  try {
    input = sc.nextInt();
  }

  catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Wrong input");
     sc.nextLine();
   }
}
while (input < 1 || input > 4);
```

Right now, if I input 'abcd' instead of integer 1-4, it gives message "Wrong Input" and the program loops, how can I make it so that it also gives "Wrong Input" when I entered integer that doesn't fulfill the boolean (input < 1 || input >4)?
So that if I entered 5, it will also give me "Wrong Input".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
if(input < 1 || input > 4) {
  System.out.println("Wrong input");
}
```

after `input = sc.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

As of now, your try-catch block is checking if `input` is an `int` type. The do-while loop is checking `input` after it has been entered, so it is useless. The condition must be checked after the user enters what he/she wants. This should fix it:

```
   do 
   {
        try
        {
            input = sc.nextInt();

            if(input < 1 || input > 4) // check condition here.
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong input");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Expected input to be an int. Try again."); // tell user that input must be an integer.
            sc.nextLine();
        }

    } while (input < 1 || input > 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    input = sc.nextInt();
    if (input >= 1 && input <= 4) {
      break;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Wrong input");
  }
  sc.nextLine();
}
```